# I can't install react-chat-engine with npm

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-chat-engine

I couldn't install

> npm install react-chat-engine

```
PS C:\Users\Edgar\Downloads\project_react\aplicacion> npm install react-chat-engine
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: aplicacion@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-chat-engine@1.5.11
npm ERR! node_modules/react-chat-engine
npm ERR!   react-chat-engine@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Edgar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Edgar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-08T04_05_17_318Z-debug.log
```

so i tried

> npm install react-chat-engine --force

**and it worked**
I know it's simple and stupid but maybe someone will use it lol

Answer (score 11):

Try to run this command

```
npm i react-chat-engine  --legacy-peer-deps
```

or you can run this command

```
npm i react-chat-engine  --force
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Or logic has been added to the peer dependencies, now `^16.8.0 || ^17.0.1` so this issue should be gone for now

Comment: The issue is still there

Answer (score 1):

Solution: `npm install react-chat-engine --legacy-peer-deps`
Alternative solution(**not recommended**): `npm install react-chat-engine --force`

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as @ankit-tiwari's ...

Comment: except for the fact that I've told that the alternative solution **is not** recommended

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. Try this command:

`npm install react-chat-engine --legacy-peer-deps`