# when i am going any dependency install i am getting an error like this

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: chat_application@0.1.0   
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.1" from react-chat-engine@1.11.22
npm ERR! node_modules/react-chat-engine
npm ERR!   react-chat-engine@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.       
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Swapnil\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Swapnil\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-28T04_06_41_338Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: try `npm i chat_application -f`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't install react-chat-engine with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66095851/i-cant-install-react-chat-engine-with-npm): `npm install react-chat-engine --force`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try using - npm install --save modulename --legacy-peer-deps